# ADX C# Data Query Union

Tags: azure-data-explorer

How do you make ADX unions in C# or python code? The UI makes sense in the web portal, but the documentation doesn't seem to make sense for the .net documentation. Maybe I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 2):

using [union operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/unionoperator) as part of a query isn't affected by which client you use (whether it's the web interface, the .NET/Python client library, etc). you simply need to make sure your query text includes using the operator, and then invoke the query.